# How do I refresh a page based on a certain day and time using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've a web page (on our intranet) that provides links to applications.  However, a job runs every Weds. at 1000 hrs.  What I'd like to do is disable the links on the page when said time is reached and enable after 30 minutes or so.

I've already created a function monitoring the time based upon a refresh.  I'd like to eliminate the refresh and have something monitoring the time in the background, so to speak (trigger) then calls a routine to disable links.  When done, reactivate the links.

How can this be accomplished in javascript?

Comment: Do you think you can trust the user's wall-clock time?

Comment: Why not do it properly and redirect to a "Scheduled Maintenance" splash screen during this period?

Comment: Shmiddty ... Thanks for the suggestion. What you've suggested may work easier than enabling/disabling the hyperlinks during this time.  I've used Alnitak code, but it clears the screen and only displays the enabled/disabled links.  I'm probably doing something wrong, but will continue to work at it!  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notwithstanding that you should be using server side logic to prevent access to those resources during the maintenance, you can help by using a timer (e.g. a `setTimeout` call once per second):

Here's a program I just knocked up that appears to work as required:

```
(function() {

    var state = null;

    (function loop() {
        var now = new Date();
        var day = now.getDay();
        var min = 60 * now.getHour() + now.getMinutes();

        var disable = (day === 3 && (min >= 600 && min < 630));
        if (disable !== state) {
             if (disable) {
                 // call your disable code
             } else {
                 // call your enable code
             }
        }
        state = disable;
        setTimeout(loop, 1000);
    })();

})();
```

The `state` variable is intended to ensure that it doesn't *repeatedly* call your disable / enable code every single second - only if there's a transition in state.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/B8u6f/ for a running example which toggles state every 10 seconds, just for test purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Works with the exception a new webpage is shown with my enabled/disabled links.  Only want to enable/disable links on current page, if possible

Comment: @Vernon there's no specific enable/disable code in my answer, the code you've added must be the cause.  You should open a new question about that.

Answer (score 3):

If you go for a JavaScript approach, it will fail if user's browser JavaScript is disabled, if you want, save the maintenance status in your database, even I do the same, when user lands on my website, the very first function I use is to check the maintenance status, if it's on redirect him to maintenance page.

Again keep refreshing your maintenance page every 30 seconds and check the status, if maintenance status shows off, redirect user back to home page

Comment: it's an intranet - he can probably require that JS is enabled.

Comment: @Alnitak I always use various ways to break applications ;) so we can't be sure

Comment: true - but in any event he should use some server side logic too.  As someone else pointed out, you can't always rely on client clock time.

Comment: @Alnitak exactly :) and when it comes to maintenance, you shouldn't leave it loose..

Comment: trust me, PHP was my first choice but you might as well ask for a trillion dollars (probably would be easier to get :) ) than asking the powers that be to enable/configure something.  Case in point, we've PHP installed but an old, unstable version... 4.3! *crying over here..LOL*)  I will try Alinak approach and see what happens. - Thanks to everyone!

Comment: @Vernon 4.3 is not that old!

Comment: Mr. Alien ... I think it's no longer supported.  It was a pain to code something (incorporating Oracle) when all this time I've been learning/running it at home using 5.x.  Nearly everyplace I've read, they discourage using 4.3, hence my desire to learn 5.x  Many functions (syntax and functionality) differ between 4.x and 5.x